# {{#if foo }}{{ foo}}{{/if}} is there a better way to check for value in handlebars.js? (Quiet Reference Notation)

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there a better way?

```
{{#if firstName }}  {{ firstName}}  {{/if}}
{{#if middleName }} {{ middleName}} {{/if}}
{{#if lastName }}   {{ lastName}}   {{/if}}
```

I often have missing data.

Comment: I suspect you'd have an easier time cleaning up the data before the template sees it. Alternatively, you might be able to add a `{{name this "firstName" "middleName" "lastName"}}` helper.

Comment: If by missing data you mean that you have no value, then why does it matter if you emit it? If you did {{firstName}} {{middleName}} {{lastName}} and one of those values didn't exist it would emit "" in its place. Otherwise if you want to control the formatting you would have to format the data before sending it to the template in the correct format, or make a specific helper for it, as mu suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use
`{{#with firstName}} {{this}} {{/with}}`

Best way would be to save the name as an object `{name:{first:'James', last:'Bond'}}` and then:

`{{#with name}}{{last}}, {{first}} {{last}}{{/with}}`

Answer (score 1):

With handlebars if the value is null or empty handlebars will spit out an empty string as Nick Kitto mentioned.

so just {{firstName}} {{middleName}} {{lastName}} would be fine. However, if the middle name were blank you'd end up with 2 spaces between the first and last name, that's about the only possible problem I can see.

Comment: but what about checking for object nullity? such as {{#if client}} {{client.name}} {{/if}} ?

Comment: You still don't need the `{#if client}`, even in that case. if `client` is null, as in your example, nothing would be still output for `{{client.name}}`.

You can test that out here if you don't believe me ;)
http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/